# Why module event in pygame has built in functions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pygame

```
  print ( type(pygame.event.Event) )
```

returns this in the python shell;

```
  <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

AFAIK, build-in functions are the only ones defined by python.

Comment: it does not do that for other classes such as Rect, pygame.rect.Rect is returned as class in the python shell.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and hence I'm removing my comment and upvoting the question... No idea myself (but I"m interested now) **:-)**

Comment: I'm not sure but `builtin_function_or_method` may mean any C/C++ function.

Answer (score 1):

This is because [`pygame.event.Event`](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src/aa82244e06e5916f77cc585c6d421354b171d6e0/src/event.c?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#event.c-1009) gets casted to a `PyCFunction`, but [`pygame.Rect`](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src/aa82244e06e5916f77cc585c6d421354b171d6e0/src/rect.c?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#rect.c-1499) for example, is defined as a type.

Comment: thank you, I was checking this file but I missed this line.